# PhpStorm - Launching the JavaScript and PHP debugger at the same time

Tags: javascript, php, debugging, phpstorm, xdebug

I have tried to set up PhpStorm to launch the JavaScript and PHP debugger at the same time following steps from [JetBrains documentation](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Debugging+PHP+and+JavaScript+code+at+the+same+time+in+PhpStorm) (section #4) but when I will run both of them I'm not able to pass first application screen which is login page. It hangs on a login process which is PHP code. PHP log returned following error message

`file_get_contents(http://localhost:8888/data/?/Ajax/&amp;q[]=/0/): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed!`

but when I do only PHP debugging (as PHP remote debug (via Xdebug) to a localhost) all works fine except breakpoints on JavaScript files.

Any tips on how to get it set up so I can debug JS code as well?

Comment: Ich didnt used the JavaScript Debugger in phpstorm yet but why you dont use the Browsers JavaScript Debugger?

Comment: @jiGL Personally I use browser debug console for JS but I have got a request to set up PHPstorm to debug whole application (PHP + Knockout.js)

Comment: File | Settings | Languages & Frameworks | PHP | Debug > try to increase "Max simultaneous connections" value

Comment: @Ástþór I had there already set to 5. No clue why is not taking any effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It came up that issue was with how Xdebug handles multiple debug sessions. I was able to fix issue by implementing steps from [JetBrains documentation](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Simultaneous+debugging+sessions+with+PhpStorm).